# xamarin Grouped Listview: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm starting with xamarin and i'm facing a problem using the listview with grouping (IsGroupingEnabled= true)

The System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is raised when i load data asynchronously  like this:

```
class RootMenuViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
      public ObservableCollection<ItemClassification> Classif { get; set; }
      public ObservableCollection<GroupItems> GroupedClassif { get; set; }
      ...
      ....
      public async Task LoadDataAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run( () =>
            {
                 authService.GetProfile( user =>
                {
                    this.Email = user.Email;
                     dicoService.GetClassification(Settings.SystemId, Settings.ResourceId, classif => {
                        foreach (var item in classif)
                        {                           
                            if (item.ItemClass.Count>0)
                            {
                                GroupItems group = new GroupItems(item.Label);
                                foreach (var elt in item.ItemClass)
                                {
                                    group.Add(elt); //creating groups raise exception
                                }
                                if(GroupedClassif.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.GroupName.Equals(group.GroupName))== null)
                                {
                                    GroupedClassif.Add(group);
                                }                                 
                             }                                                                                     
                            //Classif.Add(item);
                        }

                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Il call the asynch loading from contentPage:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
             await rootUserProfileViewModel.LoadDataAsync();            
        }
```

And here is the stack trace:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index
>
> 02-15 10:12:00.948 I/MonoDroid( 1856): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 02-15
>   10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856): System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. 02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856): Parameter name:
>   index 02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) System.Object:0336a8ee-fa98-462f-81c5-63d18afbbebd
>   (intptr,intptr) 02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   Java.Interop.NativeMethods:java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_void_method_a
>   (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*)
>   02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance,
>   Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00073] in
>   :0  02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid(
>   1856):   at
>   Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in
>   :0  02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid(
>   1856):   at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ()
>   [0x0000a] in :0  02-15 10:12:00.949
>   I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.OnDataChanged ()
>   [0x00034] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:563
>   02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.OnCollectionChanged
>   (System.Object sender,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   [0x00000] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:553
>   02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChanged
>   (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   [0x0000a] in
>   D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:771  02-15
>   10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChangedGrouped
>   (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   [0x000d5] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:798  02-15
>   10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged
>   (System.Object sender,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e,
>   System.Boolean fixWindows) [0x00008] in
>   D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:975  02-15
>   10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged
>   (System.Object sender,
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   [0x00000] in
>   D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:968  02-15
>   10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged
>   (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   [0x0000a] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:233 
>   02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy+<>c__DisplayClass33_0.b__0
>   () [0x00018] in D:\agent_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:206
>   02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid( 1856):   at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   :0  02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid(
>   1856):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv,
>   System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in
>   :0  02-15 10:12:00.949 I/MonoDroid(
>   1856):   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:61a7ea3b-2ffa-42ea-8ca3-d33b76f002b8 (intptr,intptr)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: it occurs just when i add the groups:  GroupedClassif.Add(group) in the LoadDataAsync method

Comment: Solved by using 
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                         
                    });

Comment: Nice to hear, sorry i didnt find a real issue